# Primality test for subsequences in C

Tags: c

i want to print all the prime numbers which subsequences are not primes.For example 881 is an acceptable number(8,8,81,81,88,1 are not primes) but 109 is not acceptable (1,0,9,10,19..19 is a prime number).I found the subsequences of each number by using a mask.So the problem here is that i cannot find a way to check the subsequences of each number separately.I cannot store my subsequences because I am not supposed to use arrays or functions.Can you give me an advice?I am a C begginer.Thanks in advance!

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXNUMB 100

int main (void) 
{
    int i,j,x,l,mask,max=1,mult,sub,c;
    for (i = 11 ; i < MAXNUMB; i += 2 ) {
       //
        for (j = 3; j * j <= i; j += 2) {  
           if (i % j == 0) { 
               break; 
           }           
        }
        if (j * j > i) {

            int length = 0;
            int tmp=i;
            while (tmp != 0) {
                tmp /= 10;
                length++;
            }


           for (x=1;x<length*2;x++) {
              mask=x;
              mult=1;
              sub=0;
              int num=i;
              while ( num != 0 ) {
                  if ( mask % 2 == 1 ) {
                      sub += num % 10 * mult;
                      mult *= 10; 
                   }
                   num /= 10;
                   mask /= 2;

                }
           //the problem is here.If we use a printf command for the subsequences printf("%d \n,sub); it runs perfectly


                int k=sub;

                for (l = 2; l * l <= k; l ++) {  
                    if (k % l == 0) { 
                    printf("%d \n",i);
                    break; 
                   }           
                }   


            }


        }


    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If `length` is 3, you need a 3-bit mask. In other words, `x` counts from 1 to 7. Which means that `x<length*2` should be `x<(1<<length)`.

Comment: And how this can change my code?

Comment: You haven't explained (in the question itself) what output your code is *supposed* to generate. Right now it just prints the non-prime subsequences. What do you actually want it to print.

Comment: Sotty maybe i didnt explain it very well.i want to print all the prime numbers(counter for primes is "i") that have not prime subsequences..you can check  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_prime_ideal

Answer (score 2):

I find things like this much easier to understand when they use subroutines. 
For example, for each integer from 11 to MAXNUMB you have to decide whether the integer has any prime subsequence. So write a function `int hasPrimeSubsequence(int value)`. Within this function, you will need to look at each subsequence and decide if it is prime. So write a function `int isPrime(int value)`.

Since it is non-trivial to compute a subsequence of a number,
I would even write a function
`int getSubsequenceOfNumberUsingMask(int value, int mask)`.
A function `int getMaximumMask(int value)` would also be handy.

The implementation of `hasPrimeSubsequence` then looks like this:

```
/* Returns 1 if the value has a prime subsequence, 0 if it does not. */
int hasPrimeSubsequence(int value)
{
  int has_found_prime = 0;
  int maximum_mask    = getMaximumMask(value);
  for (mask = 1; mask <= maximum_mask; ++mask )
  {
    int subsequence = getSubsequenceOfNumberUsingMask(value, mask);
    if (isPrime(subsequence))
    {
      /* We found a prime subsequence, so the answer is "yes". */
      has_found_prime = 1;
      break;
    }
  }

  return has_found_prime;
}
```

Notice that when we pass numbers into subroutines by value,
the subroutine can mess around with the values as much as it wants
(things like `mask /= 2`) without affecting the values in the caller,
so we don't have to make so many different-named copies of numbers.

The variable `has_found_prime` is how you keep track of whether any
subsequences are prime. It starts at `0` (false) because we have not
found any prime subsequences (we have not even looked for one yet).
But if *any* of the subsequences is prime, we set `has_found_prime = 1`
(true) and we never set it back to `0`.

An alternative implementation is not to even bother with the
variable `has_found_prime`; if you find a prime, just return `1` right away,
and if you get to the end of the function without having returned `1` already, then there were no prime subsequences and you return `0`.
But some people do not like that style.

You may notice that this implementation of `hasPrimeSubsequence`
does not test whether the input value is prime before it starts
trying masks. That's because I assume the last mask will select all
the digits of the original number, that is, the number itself is
one of the subsequences. If you find this does not work, all you
have to do is insert something like this before the `for` loop
(or even better, before you actually call `getMaximumMask`):

```
  if (isPrime(value))
  {
    has_found_prime = 1;
  }
```

---

**Added note:** The "mask" that you are apparently supposed to use here
is treated as a binary number with the same number of binary bits as the number of decimal digits in the number from which you want to
extract subsequences (which I'll call the "input value").

Each mask selects a subsequence from the input value;
each bit of the mask determines whether the corresponding
decimal digit of the input value is included in that subsequence.
For example, if the input value is 1237, then only the least significant
four bits of the mask are used, and

mask 0001 (binary) selects the subsequence 7,

mask 0010 (binary) selects the subsequence 3,

mask 1000 (binary) selects the subsequence 1,

mask 1011 (binary) selects the subsequence 137, and so forth.

The highest-valued mask using four bits is binary 1111,
which is 1 less than 2 to the 4th power.
This mask selects *all* the digits of a four-digit input value.

In general, if the length of the input value is N decimal digits, then the  largest possible mask is 2 raised to the Nth power, minus 1.
This is also the number of possible subsequences
(excluding the empty subsequence, which contains no digits at all).

If you do not try every mask from 1 to (2 to the Nth power, minus 1),
inclusive,
then you have not tried all subsequences and you may get a wrong answer
(guessing that the number has no prime subsequences when actually it has one).

Simply trying mask values from 1 up to `length` (the number of digits),
or even up to `2*length`, is almost always wrong.

A comment suggested something like

```
  for (mask = 1; mask < (1 << length); ++mask)
```

This will work, because `(1 << length)` is 2 raised to the `length` power,
and using `<` the last mask that will actually be tried is 1 less than that.
I still find that it makes much more readable code if you make a variable
with a reasonably self-explanatory name such as
`maximum_mask` or `end_of_masks`, and set that variable so that the loop will
run just the right number of times.

Comment: i didnt understand why we must use `maximum_mask`??it is in order to find the max subsequence of the number so we can use it like a `max`for all the subsequences of each number?

Comment: You have to put _something_ in the statement to terminate the `for` loop! So we might have a for loop that looks like `for (mask = 1; mask < ...; ++mask)` or `for (mask = 1; mask <= ...; ++mask)`. What should we replace `...` with? Your original code had `length*2` (which happens to be incorrectly calculated); `maximum_mask` is just a name for almost the same thing: the differences are that it should be computed correctly, and it is supposed to represent the maximum value you can actually uses as a mask rather than the next integer _after_ the maximum value.

Comment: ohh i get it. So i can use something like `for ( x = 1; x <= length; x++ ) {max*=2;}` and then put in the `for` loop for `( x = 1; i < max - 1 ; i++ )`

Comment: Yes, something like that.

Comment: btw it is the same if i use `for ( i = 1; i <length - 1 ; i++ )` without finding max?

Comment: No, `i < length` is usually wrong, and  `i < length - 1` is worse. I have added a note to the answer explaining why you need so many different values of the "mask".

Comment: one last question.how with your way we dont print a number two,three four etc times?for example when i try to do it  my `printf` prints 11 two times because it has two subsequences which are no-primes(1,1).thank you in advance

Comment: How many numbers do you _want_ to print? If you want to print them all, try all the subsequences in `hasPrimeSubsequence()`. If you want exactly one, print it but then end the loop inside `hasPrimeSubsequence()` so you don't print any more.

Comment: yes i want to print all the numbers exactly one time